# How to pass start parameters to workflow through WCF

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, workflow-foundation

It's possible to define some start values to an workflow using `WorkflowInstance.CreateWorkflow`, like this:

```
using(WorkflowRuntime runtime = new WorkflowRuntime())
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("First", "something");
    parameters.Add("Second", 42);

    WorkflowInstance instance = 
        runtime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(MyStateMachineWorkflow), parameters);
    instance.Start();
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

This way, a `MyStateMachineWorkflow` instance is created and `First` and `Second` public properties gets that dictionary values.

But I'm using WCF; so far, I managed to create a `Start` method which accepts that two arguments and I set that required fields by using bind on my `ReceiveActivity`:

```
using (WorkflowServiceHost host = 
    new WorkflowServiceHost(typeof(MyStateMachineWorkflow)))
{
    host.Open();

    ChannelFactory<IMyStateMachineWorkflow> factory = 
        new ChannelFactory<IMyStateMachineWorkflow>("MyStateMachineWorkflow");
    IMyStateMachineWorkflow proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

    // set this values through binding on my ReceiveActivity
    proxy.Start("something", 42);
}
```

While this works, that create an anomaly: that method *should* be called only and exactly once.

How can I start an workflow instance through WCF passing those arguments? On my tests, I just actually interact with my workflow through wire after I call that proxy method. Is there other way?

Answer (score 1):

You kinda seem to have answered your own question on how to pass parameters to start the workflow. The only question that seems to remain here is "How do i ensure people call Start first and only once?". Correct?

Ensuring it's called first can be done by setting [the IsInitiating property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isinitiating.aspx) on the OperationContractAttribute for your `Start` to true and all the other methods to false. Now, this will not stop the method from being called again, but I would think that should be handled by the fact that you can't go into that state in the workflow if you've designed the state machine properly so the WCF/WF integration should throw some kind of exception for you.

There's a good article about how to use WCF with Workflows [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179586.aspx) that you should probably check out.

Comment: hmm, interesting idea; I'll try it and come back with results; TIA